# Mac OS forgets 2nd display

Tags: macos, display, imac, sleep-wake, displayport

MacOS Catalina, 10.15.6. iMac27 late 2012.
I have connected two external displays to my iMac and it often works quite well for a long period of time, but then suddenly, after waking from display sleep (not full iMac sleep), my iMac doesn't trigger the external displays any more. Sometimes I can solve it by powering off the iMac and then hoping it will trigger the displays again, but even this is not 100% fool proof. Sometimes I have to do this multiple times.

Things I've tried:

- Only connect one display, doesn't matter.
- Unplugging display cables, wait a few minutes, no result
- Power off iMac, wait a few minutes, power on, works 50/50 of the times
- Detect displays never gives any result.

Any tips?

Comment: How are you connecting them?  What make/model monitors?

Comment: Connected both screens to the two thunderbolt ports, using a VGA Converter.
On screen is the LG 24EN33, the other is Samsung SyncMaster 226BW.